# Showing that a function is identically zero on an interval

Tags: calculus

A real-valued function $f$ defined on a closed interval $[a, b]$ has the properties that
$f(a) = f(b) = 0$ and  $f(x) = f′(x) + f′′(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a, b].$ Show that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$
in $[a, b].$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(x_0)>0$ is a local maximum for some $x_0 \in (a,b)$, then $f'(x_0)=0$ and $f(x_0)=f'(x_0)+f''(x_0) \implies f''(x_0)=f(x_0)>0$, which contradicts the fact that $f(x_0)$ is a local maximum. Flip the signs and you see that $f(x_0)<0$ is also not possible.

Comment: Today I learned: my proof was really overkill.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that you're given the differential equation $$f(x)=f'(x)+f''(x)$$which can be solved by first writing $f(x)$ in the form and plugging that into the differential equation given. $$f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$$
$$e^{\lambda x}=\lambda e^{\lambda x}+\lambda^{2}e^{\lambda x}$$
$$f(x)=\lambda f(x)+\lambda^{2}f(x)$$
Using this you get the quadratic:
$$1=\lambda^2+\lambda$$
and can use the quadratic equation on it, giving us that $$\lambda\in\{{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}\}$$
Since these give linearly independent functions when plugged into our formula for $f(x)$, the solution of our differential equation becomes this:
$$f(x)=C_1e^{\lambda_1x}+C_1e^{\lambda_2x}$$
For the proof, the precise values of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are irrelevant, just that they have opposite signs.

Note that any equation in the form $g(x)=Ce^{\lambda x}$ has a range of $(0, \infty)$, $(-\infty, 0)$, or {0}.

Therefore, for $f(x)$ to have a zero, either $C_1=C_2=0$, or $C_1$ and $C_2$ must have opposite signs

The first possibility would give $f(x)=0$, so we will show how the second solution implies that there can only be one zero, which makes the original statement $f(a)=f(b)=0$ impossible if $a\ne b$

Note that if any function $f(x)$ is both differentiable everywhere and that derivative equals zero nowhere, then it must be injective. Since an injective function cannot have more than one zero, proving that the second solution for f(x) is injective is sufficient to show that it only has one zero.

Taking the derivative of f(x) we get $$f'(x)=C_1\lambda_1e^{\lambda_1x}+C_2\lambda_2e^{\lambda_2x}$$ which is in the same form as f(x), so by an identical argument $C_1\lambda_1$ and $C_2\lambda_2$ must have opposite signs or equal zero. Since we're assuming $C_1$ and $C_2$ are not zero, and $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are not zero either, then $C_1\lambda_1\ne0$ and $C_2\lambda_2\ne0$

However, since $C_1$ and $C_2$ have opposite signs, and $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ have opposite signs by construction, then $C_1\lambda_1$ and $C_2\lambda_2$ cannot have opposite signs. This implies that if $$\exists x:f(x)=0$$$$\Rightarrow\exists! x:f'(x)=0$$

This proves that for the second case of $f(x)$, $f(x)$ must be injective, which is sufficient to show that $f(x)$ only has one zero.

Since $f(x)$ must have more than one zero, this is sufficient to show that $f(x)=0\blacksquare$